# Enabled Button When Upload Done in Dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropzone.js

I create upload files with [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)
but i want

"if users not upload and upload file in proggres in 2 form "photo" and "Documentation"  button submit still **disabled**".

"if users already done upload in 2 form "photo" and "Documentation" this button submit change to **enabled**"

This is my script

```
<html>
<head>   
    <link href="css/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
     <script>
        function submitform()
                        {
                            document.forms["form_upload"].submit();
                        }
     </script>
     <form action="send_data.php" id="mydata" name="mydata" method="POST" >
        Your Name   <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="your_name">    
     </form>

        Your Photo  
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" class="dropzone">
     <input name="folder" type="hidden" value="301">
     <input name="parameter" type="hidden" value="photo">
    </form>

        Your Documentation  
    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" class="dropzone">
     <input name="folder" type="hidden" value="301">
     <input name="parameter" type="hidden" value="documentation">
    </form>

    <center><button disabled="True"  onclick="javascript: submitform()" type="button">Submit</button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

this source code [dropzone.js](http://pastebin.com/Ab3Yqbdy) and [dropzone.css](http://pastebin.com/Dv4jKu2q)

Help me thank's :)

Comment: I edited the answer, now you can see it working in runnable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On upload success dropzone adds the preview of the uploaded element inside a div with the class `dz-success`, you can check for every form if exists that element, one way can be with a function using jQuery:

```
function checkForm() {
  var valid = true;
  if ($.trim($('input[name=your_name]').val()) === '') {
    valid = false;
  }
  $('form.dropzone').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.dz-success').length === 0) {
      valid = false;
    }
  });
  if (valid) {
    $('button[disabled=True]').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
};
```

Then on the initialization of the dropzone form you can add an event listener on the success event that calls the function to check the form in the init option, when you initialize dropzone manually you need to set auto discover option to false.

`init` [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-init):

> is a function that gets called when Dropzone is initialized. You
>   can setup event listeners inside this function.

According to the [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-success) the `success` event is triggered when:

> The file has been uploaded successfully. Gets the server response as
>   second argument. (This event was called finished previously)

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(".dropzone").each( function(){
    $(this).dropzone({
        init: function() {
            this.on("success", function() { 
                checkForm();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You also can call the validation function by adding it to the complete option.

According to the [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-complete):

> Complete is called when the upload was either successful or erroneous.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(".dropzone").each(function() {
  $(this).dropzone({
    complete: function(file) {
      if (file.status == "success") {
        checkForm();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

more on configuration options: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration

You can see it working here in runnable:

http://code.runnable.com/VgWdDZgLJkUGaepA/dropzone-success-event-for-php

Comment: i try like this > http://pastebin.com/jx9wtDAp
get error >> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$(".dropzone").each( function()

Comment: i try and i include jquery.js this source code > http://pastebin.com/FT1nbmdK   Get Error > TypeError: $(...).find(...).length is not a function
if($(this).find('.dz-success').length() == 0){

Comment: @MuhamadRidwansyah yeah, my bad. length is not a function is a javascript method i goes without parenthesis, i going to update the answer.

Comment: Still not work :'( 
you can test in localhost, this source code > https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93946653/dropzone.zip

Comment: @MuhamadRidwansyah i took a look at the code and for me works fine, what problem are you having?

Comment: you already try in localhost ??
you already try script code in dropbox ??

i already fill the text and upload 2 files
but submit still disabled

Comment: @MuhamadRidwansyah, i just realized you copied the code from the plunker, as i explained the plunk is not a correct solution, use the srcript in the answer instead.

Comment: i confused, because i already copy script from your plunker and i save already download script.js  i try test in localhost but still doesnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90627/discussion-between-wallek876-and-muhamad-ridwansyah).

Comment: Wow cool, thank;s wallek876 big many thank's for you ^_^
Thank's.